# HttpUrl newBuilder(String) usage

Tags: java, android, okhttp

To create new HttpUrl.Builder instance from existing URL I use [HttpUrl.newBuilder(String)](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-http-url/new-builder/):

```
new HttpUrl().build().newBuilder(savedUrl)
```

where savedUrl is a String containing well-formed URL.

The above fragment crashes in HttpUrl constructor because of scheme is undefined. As a workaround I use existing HttpUrl instance - less than ideal.

The questions are:

1. is newBuilder(String) the right tool for the job?
2. how newBuilder(String) should be used properly?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`parse`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html#parse-java.lang.String-) to create a new builder from an existing well-formed URL string:

```
HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(savedUrl).newBuilder();
```

Here, you can add query parameters etc. and then call `urlBuilder.build()` to get the final `HttpUrl`.

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround I'm using at the moment, was looking for a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Use `newBuilder(String)` to resolve relative links.

```
 HttpUrl.get("https://example.com/a.html")
     .newBuilder("b.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okhttp v3 provides String extension for Kotlin, so with Kotlin creating builder from URL string is as easy as:

```kotlin
savedUrl.toHttpUrl().newBuilder()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however please note that question is about Java.